# Rendering <img attribute={false} /> in JSX

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, jsx, stenciljs

I have a stencil component that can accept "draggable" prop, I want to pass the value of this prop to a child img tag when it is applied.

```
  render() {
    // this.el = Host Element
    // this.loadSrc = Image URL as String
    // draggable has to be type 'boolean | undefined'

    const shouldBeDraggable = (this.el.hasAttribute('draggable') ? this.el.draggable : undefined);

    console.log("render -> shouldBeDraggable", shouldBeDraggable); // Logs Correct Value

    return (
      <Host>
        <img
          src={this.loadSrc}
          draggable={shouldBeDraggable}
        />
      </Host>
    );
  }
```

It only renders `draggable="true"` when the host prop value is true but it does not render `draggable="false"` when the host prop value is false.

Another simplified sample;

```
 render() {
    // this.loadSrc = Image URL as String
    // draggable has to be type 'boolean | undefined'
    return (
      <Host>
        <img src={this.loadSrc} draggable={false} />
      </Host>
    );
  }
```

Unfortunately, the type of img.draggable attribute is boolean.
(JSX attribute) JSXBase.HTMLAttributes.draggable?: boolean | undefined

Passing as a string;

```
 render() {
    // this.loadSrc = Image URL as String
    // draggable has to be type 'boolean | undefined'
    return (
      <Host>
        <img src={this.loadSrc} draggable={"false" as any} />
      </Host>
    );
  }
```

This does render `draggable="true"` to the img tag Because "false" string becomes true boolean no render.

---

**How can I successfully pass the falsy case of the draggable attribute to a child an img tag?**

Comment: What exactly is the definition of this.el? Is it a value returned by document.getElementById?

Comment: I honestly think you should work to make your composition as declarative as possible, which would mean using props instead of DOM level attributes.

Comment: I don't want to override `draggable` HTML attribute, nor introduce a new attribute with a similar name. I have edited the question to avoid confusions

Comment: In that case use `this.el.getAttribute('draggable')`. Alternatively you could use refs.

Comment: this.el.getAttribute('draggable') returns a string, I could use it with a more complex if-else-parse but that is not the core of my question at the moment.

Comment: draggable={false} is working fine for me, try return (<img draggable={false} /> <Host><img draggable={false} /></Host>)
If draggable working fine outside <Host> then, please check and share Host details

Comment: How about `<div draggable={"false" as any} />`? I don't really get the point though, because you could simply treat the absence of the attribute as false?

Comment: @SimonHänisch The problem is that the browser defaults to true for <img> tag's draggable. All images are draggable unless stated otherwise.

Comment: @SamErkiner ah right yeah I think it's a bug then! I opened https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/2484 for you! (my previous suggestion doesn't work btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not possible at the time question was asked because when rendered draggable={false} in stencil, it won't pass draggable attribute for browsers to evaluate the absence of an attribute as same as false. This is only wrong for some the elements like `<img>` tag's draggable when the browser actually defaults to true.

---

However this behaviour change with this update; [0d72aee](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/commit/0d72aeea51cb754615fed74020b035b1853ad740)

On Stencil 1.15.0-1 and newer versions;

```
<img src="http://place-hold.it/200" alt="Placeholder" draggable={false} />
```

Renders as;

```
<img src="http://place-hold.it/200" alt="Placeholder" draggable="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `undefined` with `false`:

```
const shouldBeDraggable = (this.el.hasAttribute('draggable') ? this.el.draggable : false);
```

But since you want to pass `true` or `false`, you can just define:

```
const shouldBeDraggable = this.el.hasAttribute('draggable') // true or false
```

---

Further, set a class and use style:

```
<img
  src={this.loadSrc}
  draggable={shouldBeDraggable}
  className={shouldBeDraggable ? 'draggable' : 'no-draggable'}
/>

.no-draggable {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Or, use style: `user-drag:none; user-select:none;` whatever suits you.

Comment: Not related. The problem is it does not render draggable="false" when the value is false.

Comment: Not related. The problem is it does not render `draggable="false"` in output HTML when the render returns `draggable={false}`.

Comment: `src` exist, I will add it to questions to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this behavior, you have to understand how value-less attributes work in HTML.  Although there aren't too many attributes like this, imagine (for instance) the `disabled` attribute:

```
<input disabled />
```

Notice that it's not:

```
<input disabled="true" />
```

Similarly, a regular *enabled* `input` is not:

```
<input disabled="false" />
```

... it's just:

```
<input />
```

But in React, you may want to control whether the `disabled` attribute is present using a Javascript boolean value.  This, when you give an attribute a boolean value, React *simulates* HTML's behavior of including or not including the attribute, allowing you to do:

```
<input disabled={aBoolean} />
```

even though that's not how HTML literally works.  As a result, if you do:

```
draggable={false}
```

you're telling JSX *not* to add that HTML attribute.

Now what makes this weird is that `draggable` is *not* a normal value-less attribute, so it *does* expect you to actually say, in HTML, `draggable="false"`.

A simple workaround (un-tested) if you want the actual strings "true" and "false" would be to use a ternary:

```
draggable={aBoolean ? 'true' : 'false'}
```

Comment: I think the real problem is that draggable attribute defaults as true for img tag. absence of draggable mean true not false

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not change draggable's type. it has to be type 'boolean | undefined'

Comment: But what you're ultimately trying to produce is the HTML `<img draggable="false"/>`, correct?  The approach `<img draggable={aBoolean ? 'true' : 'false'}/>` should result in that.

Comment: There's also the possibility to cast to string like `<img draggable={aBoolean + ''} />` or `<img draggable={\`${aBoolean}\`} />`